# How to draw a small bivariate distribution in R?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

For illustrative purposes, I am trying to draw a small bivariate normal distribution. I would like it to be tight, centered at (3,4;1), and with a radius of 0.5 or less. By that, I mean that I would like the datapoints to be confined within a small radius.

Below see the code I am using (from this [website](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/08/simulating-form-the-bivariate-normal-distribution-in-r-1.html)); I have tried to tweak it in different ways, but the bivariate is always spread out.

```r
library(MASS)
N <- 200 # Number of random samples
set.seed(123)
# Parameters 
rho <- 0.5
mu1 <- 3.4; s1 <- 1
mu2 <- 1; s2 <- 1

# Parameters for bivariate normal distribution
mu <- c(mu1,mu2) # Mean 
sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, s1*s2*rho, s1*s2*rho, s2^2),
                2) # Covariance matrix
X <- mvrnorm(N, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma)
z <- kde2d(X[,1], X[,2], n=50)

plot(X, xlab="X label", ylab="Y label", 
    xlim=c(2,6), ylim=c(-1,3.5),pch=19, cex=.4)
contour(z, drawlabels=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: If I understand you correctly do you just want to set `s2 <- s1 <- 0.25` i.e. this will give approx 95% of values within +- 2* sd of the marginal mean i.e. == radius 0.5

Comment: @user20650 Thanks, it workes. I was trying something similar and I don't know why it wasn't working then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `s2 <- s1 <- 0.25` solves the problem as pointed out by @user20650.

```r
library(MASS)
N <- 200 # Number of random samples
set.seed(123)
# Parameters 
rho <- 0.5
mu1 <- 3.4; s1 <- 0.25
mu2 <- 1; s2 <- 0.25

# Parameters for bivariate normal distribution
mu <- c(mu1,mu2) # Mean 
sigma <- matrix(c(s1^2, s1*s2*rho, s1*s2*rho, s2^2),
                2) # Covariance matrix
X <- mvrnorm(N, mu = mu, Sigma = sigma)
z <- kde2d(X[,1], X[,2], n=50)

plot(X, xlab="X label", ylab="Y label", 
    xlim=c(2,6), ylim=c(-1,3.5),pch=19, cex=.4)
contour(z, drawlabels=FALSE, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>